# Update NFT metadata on Opensea is not working for gif to png

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, metadata, nft, opensea

I've deployed a contract that lets users mint NFTs, which will be revealed the artwork at a later time. This was due to the fact that people could guess rarity from ipfs.
The original one is *.gif and the revealed one is *.png.

[Original ipfs URL:](https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNTAGnpKrBDLaBTbpu5K1tax5gk1mKN1KS5cZGB1nAmAG)
[Revealed ipfs URL for asset #1:](https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYhd5q5q26hcYC4zXQoDLf3Zbejt7dLgtAm8Ym83WzXtS/1.png)

The contract was deployed on [Ethereum Mainnet](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8642f4BFBa8749566536Eb600B44574C3fA8b687).

I got some unexpected behavior only in images after refreshing metadata with the code below.

```
    import fetch from "node-fetch";
    
    const url =
      "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0x8642f4bfba8749566536eb600b44574c3fa8b687/";
    let startTokenID = 1;
    const endTokenID = 5000;
    
    setInterval(async () => {
      if (startTokenID > endTokenID) return;
      try {
        await fetch(url + startTokenID + "/?force_update=true", {
          headers: {
            accept:
              "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "sec-ch-ua":
              '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"',
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
            "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
            "sec-fetch-site": "none",
            "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            cookie:
              "amplitude_id_ddd6ece4d5ddebbf244a249703c9d662opensea.io=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6IjhiNDFhNmI0LTY3NDUtNDVhMS1iMTdhLTI4MzNmYmFhZmRhNlIiLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsIm9wdE91dCI6ZmFsc2UsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6MTY0MTk5MTk2ODE1NywibGFzdEV2ZW50VGltZSI6MTY0MTk5MzQ3MzkxOCwiZXZlbnRJZCI6MywiaWRlbnRpZnlJZCI6MSwic2VxdWVuY2VOdW1iZXIiOjR9; _gcl_au=1.1.1980046299.1649638918; _gid=GA1.2.1142869459.1654303903; _ga_QN8V4MT4GF=GS1.1.1654529155.5.1.1654529268.0; amp_d28823=2nhnQ-uPMMkEybOx2lSKAR.MHg3MjhhYWE0NjgxNWI4MTA2YjcyZWRkNmU3M2ZlZGYyMjMzZDNlMjlj..1g4spppcu.1g4sq37rn.ql.nj.1i8; __os_session=eyJpZCI6IjRlYzhlM2Y1LTU1ZWYtNGM2OC1hNGMxLTE5N2YyOTZkZDIyZiJ9; __os_session.sig=cGk-kIrcIZWcsqKZxlDXo2_7pHD5saW-EbgeL7GgVr0; ajs_user_id=0xeac458b2f78b8cb37c9471a9a0723b4aa6b4c62d; ajs_anonymous_id=5584d701-de15-48da-bbf3-5d902e0deedd; csrftoken=P7jEAajVMIlNjnSAgleAibNclRzPrGzP63hijSnkwcx1VFrJXp808ULSOM39MNCU; _ga=GA1.2.1868738517.1639312281; _uetsid=cc085520e59411eca6c3232868a24d9d; _uetvid=8032aa30e3a011ecae640fb1dc38d54e; amp_ddd6ec=Ii2WX9uVCIl63JobDA2eTn.MHhlYWM0NThiMmY3OGI4Y2IzN2M5NDcxYTlhMDcyM2I0YWE2YjRjNjJk..1g4tq1sad.1g4tqluej.1fc.19l.2p1; _ga_9VSBF2K4BX=GS1.1.1654562815.150.1.1654563477.0; __cf_bm=BRNExZxiPdwtk2fI_wliLM.VwmBGfsDf4W_y0dIcuyA-1654608316-0-AYb4Rv/CmF6MOuuTkBak0yS8xi1KxqY+RoQRciLqNSyTBjVNyzgbKaseSMfwfkuHmmcWqD8N91mZbgLO4PzSTjI=; sessionid=eyJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiI0ZWM4ZTNmNS01NWVmLTRjNjgtYTRjMS0xOTdmMjk2ZGQyMmYifQ:1nyZDJ:rgr7zCLDLo1AdGQk71F1T1DY_ye5aAygkletIvlIlQY",
          },
          referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
          body: null,
          method: "GET",
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
    
      console.log("Goblinpets #" + startTokenID + " complete");
      startTokenID++;
    }, 1000);
```

Even though the console showed success 200, it was not working at all.

So I developed a chrome extension for metadata refresh.

**manifest.json**

```
{
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "Opensea",
      "description": "This is Opensea Metadata Refresh Extension.",
      "version": "1.0",
    
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/*"],
          "js": ["src/content_scripts.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start",
          "all_frames": true
        }
      ]
 }
```

**src/content_scripts.js**

```
if (Number(localStorage.url) >= 1 || Number(localStorage.url) <= 5000)
  localStorage.setItem("url", 1);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function (event) {
  document
    .querySelector(
      "#main > div > div > div > div.fresnel-container.fresnel-greaterThanOrEqual-lg > div > div.item--wrapper > div.item--main > section.item--header > div    > div.item--collection-toolbar-wrapper > div > button:nth-child(1)"
    )
    .click();
  await setTimeout(() => {}, 500);
  localStorage.setItem("url", Number(localStorage.url) + 1);
  location.href = `https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x8642f4bfba8749566536eb600b44574c3fa8b687/${localStorage.url}`;
});
```

So finally refreshed metadata but got another issue.
Images are shown like videos.
Here is what I got from developer mode in [Opensea collection](https://opensea.io/collection/goblinpet).

```
<img alt="Goblin Pets #4503" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pFHXzA5ZMJ3Log_MibVOjJUsCHM_Pw546OXkv14DL8ScXz0W0S8GisQNiEu95gSRS9C6-O5R4f1ogV6Vq2cu2CRujvJRZHR1Fgayjg=w424" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
```

Showing each [asset on Opensea](https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x8642f4bfba8749566536eb600b44574c3fa8b687/4503) is even worse.

```
<video autoplay="" class="AssetMedia--video" controls="" controlslist="nodownload" loop="" playsinline="" poster="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pFHXzA5ZMJ3Log_MibVOjJUsCHM_Pw546OXkv14DL8ScXz0W0S8GisQNiEu95gSRS9C6-O5R4f1ogV6Vq2cu2CRujvJRZHR1Fgayjg" preload="metadata" style="border-radius: initial;"><source data-testid="AssetMedia--video" src="https://openseauserdata.com/files/0cdf9b98e0eedbc9aae776ada48bfaa5.mp4#t=0.001" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

As shown above, Opensea read revealed images just as posters and cached them.

I want to know why this happened and how to solve or avoid this issue.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to force OpenSea to recache your NFT art? Looking at the posted collection on my computer shows all of the NFT art as animations which I assume is intentional. Have you tried emptying the cache and forcing a hard reload in your browser? If the status is 200 then it was successful...

Comment: NFT arts should not be animations, they should be images.

Comment: Could you let me know how to force OpenSea to recache NFTs?